# Should these arguments be added or removed?

Tags: c#, cryptography, resharper, optional-parameters, named-parameters

When Resharper argues with itself, how does one know which persona to give more credence?

I think I have found some code that does confuse Resharper (this is apparently a very unusual case - after using it for a day, I think Resharper is the bee's knees/the greatest thing since liquified bread, etc.).

With this line of code:

```
ICryptoTransform Encryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(SecretKey.GetBytes(32), SecretKey.GetBytes(16));
```

Resharper tells me to *"add argument name 'rgbkey'"* and then *"add argument name 'rgbIV'"*

So that the line is then:

```
ICryptoTransform Encryptor = RijndaelCipher.CreateEncryptor(rgbKey: SecretKey.GetBytes(32), rgbIV: SecretKey.GetBytes(16));
```

When I run Resharper again, though, it says,

*"Redundant argument name specification" - "Remove argument name specification" (rgbkey)* (and then rgbIV).

It seems either way works fine, though...

Comment: Resharper really isn't telling you that either way is better than the other, it is just giving you a "Bulb Action" to do help you with something, should you need it.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Explicit parameter naming is optional on mandatory parameters, so both forms are "correct," the question is which do you like better? Like vcsjones said, Resharper is just giving you some refactoring options to suit your preferences.

Comment: That being the case, I would think they would just leave well enough alone. If at a fork in the road, a traveler takes the one less-but-almost-equally traveled, does another tell him, "Hey, don't you know this is the way to Timbuktu?" (apologies to Robert Frost and Yogi "If you come to a fork in the road, take it" Berra.

Answer (score 6):

> Resharper tells me to

Actually, it doesn't. There are (broadly) two categories of things R# communicates to the user: things it thinks the user *should* do, and things that the user might *want* to do, that it can facilitate being done more quickly.

An example of the first:

```
var i = 4;
i = 5;
DoSomething(i);
```

The assignment of `4` will produce the "Assignment is not used" inspection, with a **light bulb icon** in the left margin, offering a **quick-fix action** to fix it (by removing the assignment).

An example of the second:

```
if ((new Random()).Next() > 5)
{
    DoSomething();
}
else
{
    DoSomethingElse();
}
```

Positioning the cursor on the `if` will produce a **pencil icon** in the left margin, offering a **context action** to invert the `if`. It's not saying you *should* - it's saying, "hey, if you want to do this, just select this menu item and I'll do it for you".

Adding an argument name is in the second category, a context action. If you don't want to be offered it, you can turn it off in `ReSharper | Options | Code Editing | C# | Context Actions`. For Code Inspections, the popup menu itself offers the opportunity to change the inspection severity; or you can look at all of them in `ReSharper | Options | Code Isnpection | Inspection Severity`.

Personally there are some context actions I don't think I've ever used (eg "convert to hex"), but there are others that I find invaluable for speedy coding (various combinations of switching between `?:` and `if` and inverting, for example)