# Using Queryable instead of Extension Method

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework, resharper

ReSharper has proposed me to make the following changes:

From:

```
foreach (var item in db.Proposta.GroupBy(x => x.StatusProposta.Nome))
{
    ...
}
```

To:

```
foreach (var item in Queryable.GroupBy(db.Proposta, x => x.StatusProposta.Nome))
{
    ...
}
```

The message is: **Invoke method 'GroupBy' as static method**

I'm using **Entity Framework** and **db** is my context.

I wonder what advantages may I get or problems I can avoid with such a change.

Comment: Are you using an old version of ReSharper that doesn't understand extension methods?

Comment: These calls are equivalent. I would leave the original one. The other one feels awkward given that GroupBy is already an extension method - and extension methods were created to extend a type by allowing adding methods to this type. In other words - the idea of extension methods was to enable using newly added methods be called like other methods that already existed on the type.

Comment: @TrevorPilley I'm using the lasted version, 7.0. Just installed it.

Comment: See [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953507/should-these-arguments-be-added-or-removed/10976704#10976704) in answer to your opening "ReSharper has proposed me". In short, pencil icon is things it *can* do; lightbulb icon is things it *wants* to do.

Comment: @AakashM Very enlightening! But in this case I see a hammer, not a pencil or a bulb.

Comment: I think that must be new with 7.0 (which I don't have yet)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Resharper is just offering it as something that it can do for you. It will likewise offer to convert the static method call into as an extension method invocation.

Really it is a matter of preference - there is no advantage of one over the other - they compile to the same thing, but you *should* use it as an extension method. It's widely more popular to use the extension method syntax for extension methods rather than plain static calls when using LINQ.

Answer (score 0):

From [Extension Methods (C# Programming Guide)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383977%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

> In your code you invoke the extension method with instance method
>   syntax. However, the intermediate language (IL) generated by the
>   compiler translates your code into a call on the static method.
>   Therefore, the principle of encapsulation is not really being
>   violated. In fact, extension methods cannot access private variables
>   in the type they are extending.