# Resharper Split String literal

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resharper

I was not lucky in my 15 minutes googling. Maybe bad luck with good keyword?

Why does the Resharper suggest spliting a string in function parameter?

Example:

**From this:**

```
return PartialView("Categorias", lista);
```

**To this:**

```
return PartialView("Cat" + "egorias", lista);
```

I checked documentation here: [link](http://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/webhelp/Reference__Options__Languages__CSharp__Context_Actions.html)

And it says: 
**Split string literal - 
Splits string literal into two literals.**

I want to discover why is this a good practice, what are the fundamental idealogic behind the scenes that achieved this practice.

I don't want to do it without knowing why...

Comment: There's a difference between ReSharper's **should** suggestions, and **can** offerings. You **can** quickly split any string literal anywhere; that doesn't mean you **should**. More in [my answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10976704/71059)

Comment: Nice, now I understand. I think this is helpful when someone is passing as parameter a lonnnnnnnnnnng string. I didn't visualized that, I thought it was a "pattern" I didn't know yet.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is not a good practice. Not everything ReSharper suggests is a good practice - it just so happens that **your cursor is in that position**, so ReSharper gives you the option to split the string. Try it in any string in any position.
ReSharper has similar position based utilities, for example "convert to verbatim string" or "convert to regular string" - neither of which is "better".

Comment: Thanks for illuminating the dark path of programming.