# redundant 'IEnumerable.OfType<T>' call consider comparing with 'null' instead

Tags: c#, resharper

I'm getting this message from ReSharper. ReSharper is not proposing the change that I think would be appropriate after examining the code.  As a result I am concerned that the problem might might be my not understanding what's going on instead of ReSharper not being as helpful as it could be.

```
public interface IFrobable { }

public class DataClass
{  
    public List<IFrobable> Frobables {get; set;}

    //...
}


public class WorkerClass
{
    //...

    void Frobinate(List<IFrobable> frobables)
    { 
       //Frobs the input
    }

    void DoSomething(List<IFrobable> input>)
    {
        //Original code with Resharper on OfType<IActivity>
        Frobinate(input.OfType<IFrobable>().ToList()); 

        //Suggested change from ReSharper - Is this a generic refactor 
        //instead of issue specific?
        Frobinate(Enumerable.OfType<IFrobable>(input).ToList()); 

        //What I think should be safe to do - compiles and appears to work
        Frobinate(input);
    }
}
```

Is there any reason why my proposed change might not be safe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a regular function call:

```
Enumerable.OfType<IFrobable>(input)
```

This is the same function but invoked as an extension method:

```
input.OfType<IFrobable>()
```

In your case:

```
Frobinate(input);
```

Is absolutely fine because:

```
input.OfType<IFrobable>().ToList()
```

Equals to:

```
input.Where(x => x as IFrobable != null).ToList()
```

And in you method `input` is already defined as `List<IFrobable>` so what's the point?

Comment: RE your last question; at one point in the past input was IFrobableEx (`public interface IFrobableEx : IFrobable`) and one of the prior developers was in love with explicit casts.

Answer (score 2):

Your last case may or may not introduce a logic error.

Do you really want `Frobinate` the ability to modify the `input` list passed into `DoSomething` or just a copy of those references?

Comment: Good question.  At one point in the past there was a real cast going on and the ToList() was needed then; but it's not immediately clear if creating a copy was a desired side effect or not.

Answer (score 1):

> ```
>     //Suggested change from ReSharper
> ```

Actually, invoking `OfType` as a static method on `Enumerable` rather than as an extension method on `input` is not a **suggestion** from ReSharper - it's a **context action**. I expound on the difference [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10976704/71059).

To the actual issue:

The inspection

> Redundant '`IEnumerable.OfType<T>`' call. Consider comparing with '`null`' instead

is not one that ReSharper offers a **quick fix** solution with, I guess since there isn't a single unambiguously 'correct' change to make. It's just saying

> hey, *everything* in `input` is *definitely* going to be of type `IFrobable` - if you're trying to filter this list you might have meant to be filtering by `null`ness instead

This probably isn't relevant in your case.

As to your proposed fix - as already noted, this will mean passing **the actual `List<>` reference given to `DoSomething`** to `Frobinate`, rather than **a new `List<>` containing the same items** - if this is OK, then go for it.

Answer (score 0):

in your example you have `input` which already consists of elements of type `IFrobable` so ReSharper says that it doesn't make sense to filter them by type `IFrobable` because the filter condition is always true it proposes you to use just `input.ToList()` invocation or to filter elements buy `null`ness: `input.Where(element => element != null).ToList()`