# What is an argument name specification (for)?

Tags: c#, syntax, parameters, coding-style, naming-conventions

Resharper proposed me to add argument name specifications changing the method call from:

```
MyEvent(sender, e);
```

to

```
MyEvent(sender: sender, e: e);
```

Have not ever seen this syntax before and cannot find by google search what are the argument name specifications and why are they needed?

PS
There is a similar discussion:

- [Should these arguments be added or removed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10953507/should-these-arguments-be-added-or-removed)

but it did not address my question

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd264739.aspx

Comment: Basically, they're for methods where most of the parameters are optional. I find them a better choice than having to create many, many overloads, and they can handle use cases where overloads won't help. (When the optional arguments have the same type.) I wouldn't use them pervasively though, certainly not in methods where the parameters are all mandatory - like in your example.

Comment: Adding the parameter names can make a call more readable, but if the parameter have the same name as the variables passed as arguments, adding the parameter names doesn't make any sense.