# Explaination for "To static method invocation" ReSharper suggestion

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, resharper

Can someone help me understand the ReSharper suggestion to change:

```cs
var progs = ctx.Programs.Where(i => progIds.Contains(i.ID) && i.Projects.Any())
```

to this:

```cs
var progs = Queryable.Where
       (ctx.Programs, i => progIds.Contains(i.ID) && Enumerable.Any<Project>(i.Projects))
```

(Idea is to return programs that match a list of ids, `progIds`, and contain projects, a navigational property)

Or this:

```cs
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = ctx.Programs.Where(i => progIds.Contains(i.ID)).ToList();
```

to this:

```cs
GridView gv = new GridView();
gv.DataSource = Queryable.Where(ctx.Programs, i => progIds.Contains(i.ID)).ToList();
```

I'm specifically wondering about the benefits of this. I'm currently trying to reduce memory allocation where possible

Comment: there is no difference between those. that is what extension methods look like.

Comment: So there is no benefit to using one over the other -- just personal preference?

Comment: correct. the direct invocation is less commonly used.

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. How do I mark this answer?

Comment: static classes can have `this` keyword for first parameter of their methods. so you can use them in both ways and there is no difference. for example inside an static class you have this method. `public static void Method(this int x, int y)` then you can call it like `Method(1,2)` or `1.Method(2);`. this is how linq methods signatures defined just for readability.

Comment: In addition to the answers you have received, as far as " the ReSharper suggestion to change" goes please see [my note about the two different kinds of thing ReSharper says](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10976704/71059)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are no difference between the cases. That is actually what happens with an extension method under the covers. It is a matter of personal preference, although direct invocation is less commonly used.

Answer (score 1):

`Queryable.Where` is an extension method. It is defined as

```
public static IQueryable<TSource> Where<TSource>
            (this IQueryable<TSource> source, Expression<Func<TSource, bool>> predicate)
```

You can call it as a regular static method, passing the IQueryable as parameter, or as an extension method. The compiler will generate exactly the same code.

The extension method syntax is more readable than the static method syntax.