# Is it more efficient to use hexadecimal instead of decimal?

Tags: c#, hex, decimal, resharper

Hello i am using visual studio 2015 with .net framework 4.5 if it matters and my Resharper keeps suggesting me to switch from decimal numbers to hex. Why is that ? Is there any performance bonus if im using hex ?

Comment: I'm curious. Can you show us the exact code where R# is making this suggestion?

Comment: @juharr it is probably not making a suggestion; it is offering to perform that edit quickly, if the user wants to. [A lot of questions about R# boil down to this difference](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10976704/71059)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is absolutely no performance difference between the format of numeric literals in a source language, because the conversion is done by the compiler. The only reason to switch from one representation to another is readability of your code.

Two common cases for using hexadecimal literals are representing colors and bit masks. Since color representation is often split at byte boundaries, parsing a number `0xFF00FF` is much easier than `16711935`: hex format tells you that the red and blue components are maxed out, while the green component is zero. Decimal format, on the other hand, requires you to perform the conversion.

Bit masks are similar: when you use hex or octal representation, it is very easy to see what bits are ones and what bits are zero. All you need to learn is a short table of sixteen bit patterns corresponding to hex digits `0` through `F`. You can immediately tell that `0xFF00` has the upper eight bits set to `1`, and the lower eight bits set to `0`. Doing the same with `65280` is much harder for most programmers.

Answer (score 5):

There is absolutely no performance difference when writing constants in your code in decimal vs. hex. Both will be translated to the exact same IL and ultimately JITted to the same machine code.

Use whichever representation makes more sense for the work you are doing, is clearer and easier to understand in the context of the problem your code solves.